# Cannot connect to Bigtable Emulator from C# client

Tags: c#, .net, emulation, google-cloud-bigtable

I have the [Google Bigtable Emulator](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/emulator) running on my local machine and listening on port 8086.

Using the [C# Google.Cloud.Bigtable.Admin.V2 library](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.Bigtable.Admin.V2/latest) I want to connect to the emulator like this:

```
using Google.Cloud.Bigtable.Admin.V2;
using NUnit.Framework;
Assert.AreEqual("127.0.0.1:8086", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BIGTABLE_EMULATOR_HOST"));
var client = await BigtableTableAdminClient.CreateAsync();
```

Despite setting the environment variable as described in the emulator documentation, the library still seems to expect (cloud) credentials. I get the following error:

> The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.

What's the proper way to set the credentials when using the local emulator?

Comment: Did you provide authentication credentials by setting the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`? You may refer to this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#passing_variable).

Comment: @CatherineO no because I'm not trying to connect to the cloud but to my local emulator.  Are the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` required for the emulator too? How do I set them correctly for the emulator?

Comment: Based from your error logs, you have to define the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to pass the service account key to the client library. For more information, check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#manually)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud SDK for .NET has delayed emulator support.
In v3.0.0, support seems to have arrived as far as the code is concerned.
Please try the following code:

Google.Cloud.Bigtable.Admin.V2 2.9.0:

```cs
            var admin = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BIGTABLE_EMULATOR_HOST") switch
            {
                null => throw new InvalidOperationException("Must use emulator"),
                var host => new BigtableTableAdminClientBuilder() { CallInvoker = new GcpCallInvoker(host, ChannelCredentials.Insecure) }.Build(),
            };
```

Google.Cloud.Bigtable.Admin.V2 3.0.0:

```cs
            var admin = new BigtableTableAdminClientBuilder { EmulatorDetection = EmulatorDetection.EmulatorOnly }.Build();
```